# Python psutil collect process resources usage on Mac OS X

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, psutil

Apparently I can't get the process resources usage in Mac OS X with psutil after the process got reaped, i.e. after `p.wait()` where `p` is a `psutil.Popen()` instance. So for example, if I try `ps.cpu_times().system` where `ps` is a `psutil.Process()` instance, I get a raise of no such process. What are the other options for measuring the resources usage in a mac  (elapsed time, memory and cpu usage)?

Comment: related: [measure elapsed time, amount of memory and cpu used by the extern program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26475636/4279).

Comment: related: [How to get the max memory usage of a program using psutil in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22732932/4279)

Comment: describe how each option from [@abarnert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476066/4279) has failed in your case e.g., `r = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)`

Comment: Apparently it fits my problem, since I need to invoke just one subprocess, but I'm not quite sure as to how use it and when should I call, is it after the subprocess dies?

Comment: See [Accessing stdout when using “time” in python subproces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26412634/4279) for the usage example.

Answer (score 0):

If the process "dies" or gets reaped how are you supposed to interact with it? Of course you can't, 'cause it's gone. If on the other hand the process is a zombie, then in that case you might be able to extract some info off of it, like the parent PID, but not CPU or memory stats.

Comment: as it is shown in the comments above, you can get the info even if the process is reaped if you are its parent: [`resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413205/4279)